# Let $G$ be a group and $H_i\leq G$ for $i=1,2$. Prove $H_1\cap H_2\leq G$. Further, assume $H_i\unlhd G$ for all $i$. Prove $H_1\cap H_2\unlhd G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Please check if my strategy is correct or if there is a different way to approach this problem :)

> $\color{blue}{\text{Problem:}}$ Let $G$ be a group and $H_i\leq G$ for $i=1,2$.
>
> $(1)$ Prove $H_1\cap H_2\leq G$
>
> $(2)$ Further assume $H_i\trianglelefteq G$ for $i=1,2$. Prove $H_1\cap H_2\trianglelefteq G$.

Ideas that I have:

(1) Quite generally, for any sets $A$ and $B$, $x\in A\cap B$ iff $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Then I plan to use the subgroup criterion.

(2)We see $H_1\cap H_2\leq G$ from $(1)$. In order to show $H_1\cap H_2\trianglelefteq G$, let $h\in H_1\cap H_2$ and
$g\in G$ (be arbitrary elements). It suffices to show $(ghg)^{-1}\in H_1\cap H_2$.

Comment: I fixed up all of the formatting and unnecessary images. Please learn MathJax so that this doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy is correct but you have to make sure that you go through all the details in proving that the intersection is indeed a subgroup and similarly the intersection of normal subgroups is a normal subgroup.

Of course you may refer  to  theorems to simplify your task.

Answer (score 1):

Along the right path. For your ease suppose set $S$ is the set that contains the elements of the intersection of $H_1$ and $H_2$, then use two step subgroup test to show $S$ is subgroup of $G.$